# Support / lifetime of OpenJDK 8 in Ubuntu Xenial 16 LTS

Tags: updates, lts, openjdk

Public update of JDK8 will end 2019 - January as mentioned by Oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html.
But since Xenial has the package OpenJDK8 and Xenial is LTS until 2021 - April, does this mean that we can rely on receiving updates incl. security updates for Xenial after 2019 - January?

Thank you.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936712/what-is-the-difference-between-oracle-jdk-8-and-open-jdk-8, I think since OpenJDK references the same source as JDK then updates might not be forthcoming IMO!

Comment: thanks, but I would like a definitive answer.I asked the maintainers of the openJDK package https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+question/670348, but the answer I got was to file a bug .. and that doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: further investigation, I found Oracle's FAQ https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/update-and-faq-on-the-java-se-release-cadence.  Q7: Ok, but I don’t want new features.  I have a system in production and just want stability, performance and security updates only.  What do I do?
...
 once Oracle stops contributing our source code changes to a particular release series in OpenJDK, 
 so that we can focus on the needs of our customers, 
 other qualified contributors in the OpenJDK Community may step in to continue to maintain the release series.
 ...

Comment: and Canonical confirmed that OpenJDK is a "universe" package. so they arent the actual contributors to OpenJDK.

Comment: that settles it for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://ubuntu.com/blog/announcing-openjdk-11-packages-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts:

> *"OpenJDK 8, the former upstream LTS release, is still available and has been moved into the community-supported universe repository. Security updates for OpenJDK 8 will be provided until April 2021 for both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS."*

This means that you will be OK until April 2021, but after then you will need to find an alternative source<sup>1</sup> for OpenJDK 8 with security patches.

My advice would be to migrate your application to Java 11 before then.

---

<sup>1 - For example, [adoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html) plan to continue supporting Java 8 until *"at least May 2026"*.</sup>